# How to increment column using AWK

Tags: awk, scripting

I have the following file pattern:

```
insert_buffer cell_a 
insert_buffer cell_b
insert_buffer cell_b
...
```

I want to add one more column to the end of each line with incremented number. e.x. 0,1,2,3...:

```
insert_buffer cell_a name_0
insert_buffer cell_b name_1
insert_buffer cell_b name_2
...
```

How do I for loop using awk? Or any other solution is fine.

Comment: To make it more generic, what if I want to insert the incremental pattern in a specific column? 

    insert_buffer name_0 cell_a
    insert_buffer name_1 cell_b 
    insert_buffer name_2 cell_b

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk '{$(NF+1) = "name_"(NR-1)} 1' file
insert_buffer cell_a name_0
insert_buffer cell_b name_1
insert_buffer cell_b name_2
```

If you want to use your own variable in place of the built-in record count `NR`, then for example

```
$ awk '{$(NF+1) = "name_"i++} 1' file
insert_buffer cell_a name_0
insert_buffer cell_b name_1
insert_buffer cell_b name_2
```

If you want to insert the new field elsewhere, then one way to do that is to prepend or append it to an existing field, along with an additional output field separator `OFS` e.g. to insert before the second field

```
$ awk '{$2 = "name_"i++ OFS $2 } 1' file
insert_buffer name_0 cell_a
insert_buffer name_1 cell_b
insert_buffer name_2 cell_b
```

Comment: Thank you this works. Is there a way to incr var i let's say? insert_buffer cell_a -cell_name_${i} -net_name_${i}

Comment: @Bryan see edit - is that better?

Comment: Thank you! How do I make it more generic? Say I wanna insert the 'name_${i}' in any column, not just the last column?

Comment: Nice hack setting the number of fields to include the new field.  I'm not an awk guru; is that "1" at the end a short-cut to print the current line?

Comment: @MarkStewart yes the default awk action is to print the whole record if a rule evaluates 1 (or true) - the longhand equivalent would be `{print}`

Comment: The (NR-1) trick left me speachless!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the `sed` editor as given:

Note that since `sed` has no notion of arithmetic, it can be done by other means.

```
the variable $n stores the column number where you want the new data placed.

n=2;
sed -ne 1i\\ -e 0 -e p\;= yourfile |\
sed -nE "N;s/\S\+/&\n/$n;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n/\2 name_\1 /p"
```

---

### Results

```
insert_buffer name_0  cell_a
insert_buffer name_1  cell_b
insert_buffer name_2  cell_c
```